# R 'move' package - using own data - error: There are NA timestamps records

Tags: r, csv, posixct

`R` novice here! I'm trying to use my own animal tracking data (.csv) through the 'move' package but as I'm importing/projecting it, `R` gives me an error. Code below.

```
track <- read.csv("Tracking_Data_CSV.csv")

datetime2 <- as.POSIXct(paste(track$Trk_date, track$Trk_time), format = "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M")

track2 <- move(x=track$long, y=track$lat, time=datetime2, data = track,
proj=CRS("+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84"), animal = track$Toad.)

**Error in validityMethod(as(object, superClass))  :
```

There are NA timestamps records**

I've tried lots of different ways (doing the as.POSIXct conversion within the move function, etc.) and I still get the same error above. There are definitely no NAs in either my date or time columns in the original dataset so I am just really confused as to what isn't working! Any ideas to try really appreciated - I can't find anything online.

Comment: Can you post a sample/reasonable facsimile of your data (preferably created with `dput(your_data)`) so your problem is reproducible?